# How to find if LI has children UL

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following structure:

```
<ul>
    <li class="static">
        <ul class="static">
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="static"></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the first LI element has UL inside it but the next one doesn't. Is there a way to find out through jquery if a certain LI has UL inside it or not? I want to do something like this:

```
if(li has children ul)
{
    do something
}
```

**EDIT**

I tried the following but it shows "YES" for all cases. Here's my code and HTML. In the HTML below, only "Link2" contains child UL and not Link1 and Link3. I just want to do some operation when a user clicks on some LI which contain child UL.

**CODE**

```
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div > div > ul > li > a').click(function()
{
   if($('li:has(> ul)'))
      alert("yes");
  else
     alert("no");
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ms-core-navigation" id="DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar">
 <div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_QuickLaunchNavigationManager">
  <div class=" noindex ms-core-listMenu-verticalBox" id="zz14_V4QuickLaunchMenu">
   <ul class="root ms-core-listMenu-root static" id="zz15_RootAspMenu">
    <li class="static">
     <a href="link1.php" tabindex="0" class="someclass1">
      <span class="someclass2">
       <span class="menu-item-text">Link1</span>
      </span>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li class="static">
     <a href="link2.aspx" tabindex="0" class="someclass3">
      <span class="someclass2">
       <span class="menu-item-text">Link2</span>
      </span>
     </a>
     <ul class="static">
      <li class="static">
       <a href="Link2A.php" tabindex="0" class="someclass1">
        <span class="someclass2">
         <span class="menu-item-text">Link2A</span>
        </span>
       </a>
      </li>
      <li class="static">
       <a href="Link2B.php" tabindex="0" class="someclass1">
        <span class="someclass2">
         <span class="menu-item-text">Link2B</span>
        </span>
       </a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="static">
     <a href="Link3.php" tabindex="0" class="someclass1">
      <span class="someclass2">
       <span class="menu-item-text">Link3</span>
      </span>
     </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why not try this? if($('li ul)'))
      alert("yes");
  else
     alert("no");

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In your specific code, it looks like you need to use `this` to refer to the element that was clicked on and then find the parent `<li>` from there so you are operating on only the `<li>` that had the click in it:

```
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div > div > ul > li > a').click(function() {
   if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length) {
       // the clicked on <li> has a <ul> as a direct child
   }
});
```

---

In jQuery, you can use either `.find("ul")` or `.children("ul")` depending upon whether you're looking for only immediate descendants or any descendant.

For example, if you want to find out if a particular `<li>` tag that you already have a reference to has a `<ul>` as a direct child, then you can do this:

```
if ($(el).children("ul").length) {
    // el has a ul as an immediate descendant
}
```

Or, if the ul can be any descendant, then you can use this:

```
if ($(el).find("ul").length) {
    // el has a ul as a descendant at any level
}
```

---

If you want to just find all the `<li>` tags with `<ul>` below them, then you have these two options:

You can get a list of all `<li>` tags with a `<ul>` anywhere inside of it like this:

```
var tags = $("li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("ul").length !== 0;
});
```

If you only want immediate descendants, you can use this:

```
var tags = $("li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).children("ul").length !== 0;
});
```

---

You can then operate on those particular `<li>` tags by just calling a method on the jQuery object without using the `if`:

```
var tags = $("li > ul").addClass("hasSubMenu");
```

Comment: Added a fix to your specific code to the start of my answer (now that you've shown your code).

Comment: This line in your code did the trick for me "if($(this).closest("li").children("ul").length)"

Answer (score 7):

This is what you looking for

```
$('li:has(> ul)');
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92PJ5/)

Comment: This tells the OP if there's any li with a ul under it, but the OP asked how to tell if a "certain" li has a UL under it.

Comment: Works great for me too

Answer (score 3):

use the [:has selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector)

like

```
$('#DeltaPlaceHolderLeftNavBar div > div > ul > li > a').click(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('li').has('ul').length) {
        alert("yes");
    } else {
        alert("no");
    }
});
```

Comment: This gets a list of li tags with a ul under it, but the OP asked how to tell if a "certain" li has a UL under it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for direct children under your li's:

```
if($('li>ul').length > 0){

}
```

or this to search the whole li for a ul:

```
if($('li').find('ul').length > 0){


}
```

EDIT

I didn't see the word 'certain' in your post, so heres an edit:

You have an ul > li > ul structure, I have made this same structure but a little more basic, so you can see what happens and how it works.
HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Level 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

JS:

```
$("ul>li>a").click(function(e){
    if($(this).parent().find('ul').length > 0){
     alert('Yeah, we have a ul');   
    }else{
     alert('Nope, no ul');   
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Milanzor/NsPP7/ (My HTML)

and http://jsfiddle.net/Milanzor/NsPP7/1/ (Your HTML)

Comment: This tells the OP if there's any li with a ul under it, but the OP asked how to tell if a "certain" li has a UL under it.

Comment: Tried but didn't work. Have pasted HTML above and my code which I am using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use length as well

```
if($('li.static').children('ul').length > 0) {
       //do something...
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but didn't work. I have pasted my complete HTML above.

Answer (score 0):

To se if the direct descendant of the current clicked LI has a UL I use the method below, this makes sure that if you clicked a menu item in the submenu it does not collapse the previous menu:

**HMTL:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
             </ul>
       </li>
       <li><a href="#">Item</a>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item</a></li>
             </ul>
       </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Script:**

```
var nav = $('nav');

nav.find('li>a').on('click',function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var $li = $this.parent();

    //set active state to clicked menu item:
    $li.addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active open');

            //look if there is a UL after the A, if so it contains submenu:
    if($this.next().is('ul')){
        $li.toggleClass('open');
    }

});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1fykp7wx/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(".shop-nav > div >ul > li > ul").prev("li").attr("data-toggle","dropdown");
```

Comment: Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See:  [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think each method is for you . Try to iterate over li to find if it has ul as a children or not, if yes then turn the paticular list background red or whatever you want.

```
  $('.top-menu > ul > li').each (function(){
    if($(this).children('ul').length) {
      $(this).css('background', 'red');
    }
  });
```